# perform two computation in two column and the answer will be save in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I perform a autocompute in my database ex. the value of Stock and Quantity(Quantity-Stock) the answer will be save in CarryO column

create.php

```
<?php
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if($con)
 {
mysql_select_db("testproduct",$con);
 }

 if($_POST)
{


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id = '".$_POST['pid']."'");
    $prod = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $pname = $prod['name'];
    $actualprice = $prod['actualprice'];
    $sellprice = $prod['sellprice'];
    $stock = $prod['Stock'];

    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    $saledate = $_POST['saledate'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $profit = $_POST['profit'];
    $carryO = $_POST['carryO'];
    $sells = $_POST['sells'];
    $expense = $_POST['expense'];
    try{

        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tblsales(pname,gname,saledate,quantity,actualprice,sellprice,carryO,sells,expense,profit,stock) 
                                VALUES(:upname,:ugname,:usaledate,:uquantity,:uactualprice,:usellprice,:ucarryO,:usells,:uexpense,:uprofit,:ustock)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":upname", $pname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ugname", $gname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usaledate", $saledate);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uquantity", $quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uactualprice", $actualprice);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usellprice", $sellprice);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ucarryO", $carryO);
        $stmt->bindParam(":usells", $sells);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uexpense", $expense);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uprofit", $profit);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ustock", $stock);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Successfully Added";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

thanks for your help just new in php and please let me know if I can use your code or its only a example

Comment: First and one of the basics of `database`, you should learn about `Keywords and Reserved Words`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: your putting an array to pname variable not the data of the column and then your using it to bindParam. bindParam only allow string not an array, so you have to use mysql_fetch_array to extract the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id = ".$_POST['pid']);
echo $prod;
$pname = [$prod['name']];
```

Into:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id = '".$_POST['pid']."'");
$prod = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$pname = $prod['name'];
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in create.php on line 8 $prod = mysql_fetch_array($sql); is line 8
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pname' cannot be null

Comment: yep still the same warning

Comment: It means the error is from the query. Show us your table structure of `tblproduct`.

Comment: I just screenshot it

Comment: `Name` and `Status` are `reserved-words` so you should not be using those as `column name`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this.

```
$prod =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id = ".$_POST['pid'],$db_con); //$db_con must be your database connection

if(!$prod) { die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); } //always check if your query is properly done.

$pname = ""; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($prod)) { 
$pname = $row["name"]; }
```

also if you are fetching only one column which is the `name` then be specific to your query for fastest result. e.g. `"SELECT name FROM tblproduct WHERE id = ".$_POST['pid']`

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in  on line 7 $prod =  mysql_query is the line 7
Database query failed: